# git not uploading all files

Tags: git, amazon-ec2, gitlab

I have a project which is fairly big (200MB) and i wanted to push it to my gitlab server (in amazon ec2) and when i push it seems fine, but when upload reaches about 8% the push suddenly "completes" and this is what i get in the console:

```
Counting objects: 464, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (421/421), done.
Writing objects: 100% (464/464), 15.07 MiB | 52 KiB/s, done.
Total 464 (delta 47), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@IP:myrepo.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

when i try to git push again i get

```
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Everything up-to-date
```

i deleted the git repo on the server and tried again but it happend again
and i have no idea why so i came here.
has this ever happend to one of you before?

I am running the turnkey GitLab AMI from Amazon aws marketplace on a microinstance, if this is somehow relevant.

Comment: What fails to push - files, branches?  Can you give a specific item that isn't pushing properly?

Comment: Your message seems to imply everything has been pushed correctly. I.e. you pushed the master branch and it has been pushed. Could it be you forgot to commit, or you committed to a different local branch and did not merge with master?

Comment: i have only one branch which is master, and on my Gitlab server i can see the branch in the web ui, but when i browse the files most of them are missing. However, this files are definitely in the git repository on my local pc. Unfortunalty i can not tell the specific file where the upload broke, is there some way to tell? logs?

Comment: there is no way i forgot to add the files. i made a clean new git repository, added with "git add . " (no .gitignore), then i commited, added the origin and pushed

Comment: What does 'git status' show on your local git? It should be "on branch master nothing to commit"

Comment: @EliAlgranti shows exactly what you wrote.

Comment: @joschua011 then I'm stumpted every thing indicates the files were uploaded correctly, if you can't see them on the server it is for some other reason (permissions maybe.)

Comment: it just cant be because it cant upload 200MB in 5 min or so with 6o kbps, also i know that the repostories on my server get stored in /home/git/repositories/ and when i do "du -h" there it shows 16M

Comment: Git may have streamed the data into a pack-file, which is compressed... so it could realistically be only 16MB in size.  Have you cloned the project somewhere else and checked the files?

Answer (score 1):

Stopping at 8% may be fine is for example if you have only a few large files that would account for 92% of the size.

Best way to check you have everything you want on the remote server would be to clone that repo somewhere else and check what you have.